# Yii2 relation with parameter

Tags: activerecord, yii2

Is it possible and what would be the best way to define a relation with a parameter in Yii2.

Situation is simple. I have table *texts* and *texts_regional*. *texts_regional* of course has foreign keys *text_id* and *lang_id*.

Gii generated a method to get all regional texts but I dont need that on the frontend. I just need in the current language.
Generated method is:

```
public function getTextsRegionals()
{
    return $this->hasMany(TextRegional::className(), ['text_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Tried this but it's probably not right:

```
public function getReg($langId=null)
{
    if($langId === null && Yii::$app->session->has('langId')) {
        $langId = Yii::$app->session->get('langId');
    }
    return $this->hasOne(TextRegional::className(), ['text_id' => 'id', 'lang_id'=>$langId]);
}
```

I need data from both tables so I'd like to eager load this.

Is it just better to use separate method and manually construct the query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read in documentation that it's possible to do ->onCondition so wrote a method like this:

```
public function getReg($langId=1)
{
    if(Yii::$app->session->has('langId')) {
        $langId = Yii::$app->session->get('langId');
    }

    return $this->hasOne(TextRegional::className(), ['text_id' => 'id'])->onCondition(['lang_id' => $langId]);
}
```

$langId is set in main controller.

But I ended up using *TextRegional* model and joined with *Text* model to set condition.
Made a *TextRegionalQuery* class and added a new method:

```
public function byCode($code)
{
    if(Yii::$app->session->has('langId')) {
        $langId = Yii::$app->session->get('langId');
    } else {
        $langId = 1;
    }

    $this->joinWith('text0')
        ->andWhere("lang_id = '".$langId."'")
        ->andWhere("texts.code = '".$code."'");

    return $this;
}
```

Using it like this:

```
$ft = TextRegional::find()->byCode("footer_text")->one();
```

Or

```
$news = TextRegional::find()->byType(2)->visible()->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
* relation with current LangContractTemplate
*/
public function getCurLangContractTemplate()
{
    if(isset(Yii::$app->user->identity->u_lang) && !empty(Yii::$app->user->identity->u_lang))
        $langId = Yii::$app->user->identity->u_lang;
    else
        $langId = \Yii::$app->language;

        return $this->hasOne(LangContractTemplate::className(), ['lcont_cont_id' => 'cont_id'])->onCondition(['lcont_lang_id' => $langId]);
}

//------------------OR------------------

/**
 * relation with language table
 */
public function getContractByLang()
{
    return $this->hasOne(LangContractTemplate::className(), ['lcont_cont_id' => 'cont_id']);
}

/* and Get data  */
$contract_content = ContractTemplate::find()
->joinWith(['contractByLang' => function($query) use ($lang) {
    return $query->where(['lcont_lang_id' => $lang]);
}])
->one();
```